# alias conflict namespace c#

Tags: c#

Looking for an explanation.

I have the same name space in two different assemblies.  Say

```
NsA.xxx.NsB
```

Now I created an alias to resolve the issue and called it xxx.
I left "global" as the alias namespace for the other assembly.

The trouble is that "xxx" as an alias conflicted with "xxx" namespace part.  I resolved the Issue by haveing my alias named "XXX".  Now there was no conflict and everyone returned to thinking happy thoughts.

This is unexpected (to me).  Is this a bug?

Comment: Your question is *very* unclear. Please give a short but complete example.

Comment: If you have conflicts, capitalizing an alias is definitely *NOT* the way to resolve this.

Comment: Oddly enough, there are two parts to the System.Configuration namespace. One of them is apparently part of System by default, and the other can be brought in by reference. In that case, if you look at References, you will see System.configuration -- lower-case "c", apparently to avoid a filename collision with String.Configuration. Or so I presume. If so, then even Microsoft does it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug. That's how you resolve conflicts when multiple assemblies used in code have classes with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

C# is case sensitive so there is a distinct difference between namespace xxx and namespace alias XXX.

Example:

```
using Company.People.Employee;
//using Contractor.People.Employee;
using PEOPLE = Contractor.People;

//People.Employee is not the same as PEOPLE.Employee, even though they look very similar
```